# How to identify if text encoding issue is my processing error or carried from the source pdf

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, utf-8, character-encoding, apache-tika

I have a selection of pdfs that I want to text mine. I use tika to parse the text out of each pdf and save to a .txt with utf-8 encoding (I'm using windows)

Most of the pdfs were OCR'd before I got them but when I view the extracted text I have `"pnÁnn¿¡c"` instead of `"Phádraig"` if I view the PDF.

**Is it possible for me to verify the text layer of the PDF (forgive me if thats the incorrect term)** Ideally without needing the full version of Acrobat

Comment: As a quick check, you can highlight + copy-paste to an editor. To some extent, the result depends on the viewer, but it should enable you to tell whether the distortion is pure OCR (I wouldn't be surprised in the case of Old Irish) or if you have an additional source of noise due to an encoding mismatch.

Comment: Can you make this an answer to get points? It did work and points to those being OCR errors thankfully. (if I kept reading I would have seen Phadraig as being correctly encoded elsewhere in the text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are dealing with scanned books with "hidden OCR", ie. the PDF shows an image of the original document, behind which there is a layer of OCRed text.
That allows you to use the search function and to copy-paste text out of the document.

When you highlight the text, the hidden characters become visible (though this behaviour maybe depends on the viewer you use).
To be sure, you can copy-paste the highlighted text to a text editor.
This will allow you to tell if you are actually dealing with OCR quality this terrible, or if your extraction process caused mojibake.
Since OCR quality heavily depends on language resources (dictionaries, language model), I wouldn't be surprised if the output was actually that bad for a low-resource language like Gaelic (Old Irish?).